# How to fix "Undefined property: Register::$encrypt" in PHP codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-encryption

When I am submitting my form in CodeIgniter, I get this error Message: Undefined property: Register::$encrypt. I want to hash the password that's the reason I used the encrypt.

I have tried to include encrypt library in autoload.php but still another error pops up.

this is where the error is popping up.
function validation(){

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name','Name','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email','Email Address','required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[codeigniter_register.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password','Password','required|trim');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){

        $verification_key=md5(rand());
        $encrypted_password = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('user_password'));
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('user_email'),
            'password' => $encrypted_password,
            'verification_key' => $verification_key


        );
        $id=$this->register_model->insert($data);
        if($id > 0){
            $subject='Please verify email for login';
            $message="
                <p>Hi".$this->input->post('user_name')."</p>
                <p>Verify your email for login to this system. Click this <a href='".base_url()."register/verify_email/".$verification_key."'>link</a>.</p>
                <p>Use this link to log in in to this system.</p>
                <p>Thanks You.</p>
            ";

            $config = array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
                'smtp_port' => 80,
                'smtp_user' => 'root',
                'smtp_pass' => 'root',
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' =>TRUE
            );

            $this->load->library('email',$config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('info@icode.info');
            $this->email->to($this->input->post('user_email'));
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);
            if($this->email->send()){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Check in your email for verification mail');
                redirect('register');
            }

        }

    }
    else{
        $this->index();
    }
```

I expected after submitting the form to give an alert or send the data I have filled in my form to the database,

Comment: You probably forgot to load the encryption library  I don't use the new version of CI but I imagine it should be something like `$this->load->library('encryption');`

Comment: This works. $hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); // 60char see php.net

Comment: Hello, I have loaded this library but still the same error.

Comment: this is the entire code<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller {
 
 public function _construct(){
  parent::_construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->library('encryption');
  $this->load->model('register_model');
 }

Comment: `this is the entire code` - It's hard to tell with incomplete code what is `Register` the class code you show? or is it something else.  It's not complete its a method of a class.  I assume its a controller named Register but I have no real idea if that is the case.  FYI - we don't need the Whole code, just enough context to know what it is we are looking at.

Comment: yes register is the controller

Comment: Loading it should work, just make sure it's loaded before you use it, if you use it in multiple methods it may be better to load it in the constructor.

Comment: since i can't paste the entire code here, this is where i have loaded my libraries  public function _construct(){
  parent::_construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->library('encryption');
  $this->load->model('register_model');
 }

Comment: Yea that looks fine you can use the backtic ` for code in comments, I've seen issues with calling `parent::__construct` too late, such as after loading the libraries, but that doesn't seem to be the case here..  So I am not sure, have you tried printing out the object after loading it.  `$this->load->library('encryption'); print_r($this->encryption)`

Comment: It's spelled wrong, no `tion`  For example  encryption vs encrypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the encryption libarary

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
$encrypted_password = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('user_password'));
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

> **Once loaded**, the Encryption library object will be available using:
>   `$this->encryption`

**Update:**

As you mentioned your loading it in the constructor I took another glance at it:

It looks like a spelling error

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
 ...
$this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('user_password'));
```

instead of

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
 ...
$this->encryption->encode($this->input->post('user_password'));
```

Also in the documentation it's presented this way

```
$ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);
```

Simple mistake, took me a few minutes of looking at it too see it too.  I never type things out if I can avoid it, I copy/paste everything.  Mostly that is because my spelling and stuff is bad (Dyslexia) but it can avoid some issues like this... lol

Glad we got it sorted for you!

Comment: Thank you solved that. After that am now receiving this error An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_Encryption::encode() on the same line

Comment: I would go by the Documentation for your version of CI, I never used CI3 so it may be you looked at some old documentation.  I think it's just encrypt. But you can change the cipher with `$this->encryption->initialize(...)` etc.

Comment: Even in CI 2 I wrote my own Encryption layer.  Not something I would suggest doing unless you really know your stuff.  We have very strong security here so I had to do custom code for what we wanted to do.  We don't use CI for login or member management so it wasn't password related.  Basically we use  asymmetric encryption for a file storage system.  Which is not something the basic encryption library can handle, due to file sizes ect (files have to be chunked and encrypted then rebuilt to manage memory)

Comment: I am just starting to learn CI. You guys seem to have a good and complex system. I am glad I have found someone like you

Comment: I'm on the fence about using CI3 or Laravel for my next Big Project.  CI is great and I havent looked at what the new version has ORM and Template wise.  But Larval has a lot of nice features but I think the learning curve will be steeper for less experienced programmers.   I have almost 10 years PHP experience, so I don't see that as to much of a hurdle for myself.  CI is very easy to get started and pretty flexible for the most part, It's a good choice.

Comment: I have 1 year of at least writing PHP codes for basic programs. I haven't developed any big project for any client yet.

Comment: When I wrote our CI2x application Larval wasn't mature enough for me to use it.  They were also in the mists of a redo with some backwards incompatible changes, so I went with CI.  It's been good works great.

Comment: Nice, keep at it.  I used to do Auto Manufacturing then got into this and haven't regretted a day.  Technically I am a CIO, I have built maybe 100 websites (a lot have been replaced as my last 6 years are with the same company) and several B2B APIs and services.  A few payment gateway plugins (such as a Chase Orbital gateway plugin for Drupal, that was years ago) etc.  I love it, I turn 0's to 1's and solve complex business problems with my mind... pretty amazing

Comment: It's amazing this has been my passion since the very first day I set my eyes on a computer. feels good to talk computer language.

Comment: Larval has a lot of great features that at least CI2 was lacking, such as a Database ORM layer, a robust template engine.  It has support for Queuing systems and events etc..  its very PSR oriented - such as using service providers and dependency injection wrappers.  They are more complex topics which is why I said it may be a bit harder to learn, but that is just my Opinion as I haven't used it yet, just done some research.

Comment: I tried to install it in my machine but it's really hectic and complex. was my number one option to learn, but I decided that I will not waste a day installing it first I should learn CI